# Problem with writing files in a Discord.py Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, python-aiofiles

I'm trying to write out to a file a user's answers on a poll, specifically the questions that got a "yes" answer. My code looks like this.

```
@bot.command()
async def poll(ctx):
count = 0
for _ in questions_list:
    count += 1
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Question #" + str(count), description=_)
    question = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await question.add_reaction("✅")
    await question.add_reaction("❌")
    await asyncio.sleep(delay=delay)
    for _ in question.reactions:
        if  _ == "✅" and _.author == ctx.author:
            data = f"Question #{count} | {_}"
            async with aiofiles.open(str(ctx.author), 'w+') as out:
                await out.write(data)
                await out.flush()
            print(f"Done, #{count}")
```

Unfortunately, I can't find any files after running the bot and going through the questions myself, I can't find any file. I searched the same folder where my main.py file is located.
The bot asks the questions as predicted, adds the two reactions, sleeps for 40 seconds in my test, and then just moves to the next one, I'm sure the for loop or the if statement or both are failing because I don't get anything printed out to my console.
If you have any better approach to this problem, I would love to know about it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `_` for meaningful loop variables, and why are you re-using it inside nested loops?  You should avoid both practices. Can you out a print inside the `for _ in question.reactions` and before the `if`?  You might also want to try reading the files immediately after writing them and seeing if the data is there.